# Using Highcharts to create an items chart (aka "waffle" chart) - how to I control padding?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, visualization, waffle-chart

I am using Highcharts to create a waffle chart. Here's a good example:

https://datavizproject.com/data-type/percentage-grid/

[image: waffle chart]

Highcharts calls them "item charts", and they work pretty well.

However, I can't figure out how to control the spacing/padding between the items.

I've tried using the `itemPadding` property, but that only seems to set the padding between the ***rows***, but not the ***columns***.

Here's a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/stuehler/frt80u2p/4/

As you can see in this screenshot below, the row padding is 1px (`itemPadding: 1` - that's what I want), but the column padding is much larger:

[image: Screenshot from jsfiddle - column padding too wide]

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'item'
  },

  series: [{
    marker: {
      symbol: 'square'
    },
    itemPadding: 1,
    rows: 10,
    data: [
      {
        name: 'Male',
        y: 43
      },
      {
        name: 'Female',
        y: 57
      }
    ]
  }]
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You might be able to get effect with custom marker? from docs 

Additionally, the URL to a graphic can be given on this form: 'url(graphic.png)'. Note that for the image to be applied to exported charts, its URL needs to be accessible by the export server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to extend/overwrite, here is some food for thought on how to achieve the spacing. Take the examples below as they are. The code is not production ready in terms of maturity or testing.

#### Example 1

```
(function (H) {
    const ItemSeries = H.Series.types.item;
    H.wrap(ItemSeries.prototype, 'drawPoints', function (proceed) {
        const originalPlotWidth = this.chart.plotWidth;
        this.chart.plotWidth = this.chart.plotHeight;

        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

        this.chart.plotWidth = originalPlotWidth;
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

It just sets the `plotWidth` such that it is equal to `plotHeight` during the call to `drawPoints`, giving each cell the same width and height. It ends up showing correctly for some simple demo scenarios, but the chart is shown aligned to the left.

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/6zugn5Ly/). It should perhaps be using `Math.min` for width and height.

#### Example 2

```
(function (H) {
                console.log(H);
       H.Series.types.item.prototype.drawPoints = function() {
                const series = this, options = this.options, renderer = series.chart.renderer, seriesMarkerOptions = options.marker, borderWidth = this.borderWidth, crisp = borderWidth % 2 ? 0.5 : 1, rows = this.getRows(), cols = Math.ceil(this.total / rows);
                
                const cellWidth = Math.min(this.chart.plotWidth / cols, this.chart.plotHeight / rows), cellHeight = Math.min(this.chart.plotWidth / cols, this.chart.plotHeight / rows), itemSize = this.itemSize || Math.min(cellWidth, cellHeight);
                const leftPadding = Math.max(0, (this.chart.plotWidth - (cellWidth * cols)) / 2);
                
                let i = 0;
                /* @todo: remove if not needed
                this.slots.forEach(slot => {
                    this.chart.renderer.circle(slot.x, slot.y, 6)
                        .attr({
                            fill: 'silver'
                        })
                        .add(this.group);
                });
                //*/
                for (const point of series.points) {
                    const pointMarkerOptions = point.marker || {}, symbol = (pointMarkerOptions.symbol ||
                        seriesMarkerOptions.symbol), r = H.pick(pointMarkerOptions.radius, seriesMarkerOptions.radius), size = H.defined(r) ? 2 * r : itemSize, padding = size * options.itemPadding;
                    let attr, graphics, pointAttr, x, y, width, height;
                    point.graphics = graphics = point.graphics || [];
                    if (!series.chart.styledMode) {
                        pointAttr = series.pointAttribs(point, point.selected && 'select');
                    }
                    if (!point.isNull && point.visible) {
                        if (!point.graphic) {
                            point.graphic = renderer.g('point')
                                .add(series.group);
                        }
                        for (let val = 0; val < (point.y || 0); ++val) {
                            // Semi-circle
                            if (series.center && series.slots) {
                                // Fill up the slots from left to right
                                const slot = series.slots.shift();
                                x = slot.x - itemSize / 2;
                                y = slot.y - itemSize / 2;
                            }
                            else if (options.layout === 'horizontal') {
                                x = cellWidth * (i % cols);
                                y = cellHeight * Math.floor(i / cols);
                            }
                            else {
                                x = leftPadding + (cellWidth * Math.floor(i / rows));
                                y = cellHeight * (i % rows);
                            }
                            x += padding;
                            y += padding;
                            width = Math.round(size - 2 * padding);
                            height = width;
                            if (series.options.crisp) {
                                x = Math.round(x) - crisp;
                                y = Math.round(y) + crisp;
                            }
                            attr = {
                                x: x,
                                y: y,
                                width: width,
                                height: height
                            };
                            if (typeof r !== 'undefined') {
                                attr.r = r;
                            }
                            // Circles attributes update (#17257)
                            if (pointAttr) {
                                H.extend(attr, pointAttr);
                            }
                            let graphic = graphics[val];
                            if (graphic) {
                                graphic.animate(attr);
                            }
                            else {
                                graphic = renderer
                                    .symbol(symbol, void 0, void 0, void 0, void 0, {
                                    backgroundSize: 'within'
                                })
                                    .attr(attr)
                                    .add(point.graphic);
                            }
                            graphic.isActive = true;
                            graphics[val] = graphic;
                            ++i;
                        }
                    }
                    for (let j = 0; j < graphics.length; j++) {
                        const graphic = graphics[j];
                        if (!graphic) {
                            return;
                        }
                        if (!graphic.isActive) {
                            graphic.destroy();
                            graphics.splice(j, 1);
                            j--; // Need to substract 1 after splice, #19053
                        }
                        else {
                            graphic.isActive = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
}(Highcharts));
```

This is essentially a full overwrite of the `drawPoints` code, using [the original as a source](https://code.highcharts.com/modules/item-series.src.js). It defines the `cellWidth` and `cellHeight` variables differently from the original, making the cells square. It also defines a `leftPadding` variable to be able to center the chart in the plot.

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/8tvgrzme/).

Answer (score 2):

From the docs it looks like you can set a width ONLY on image markers.

width: number
Image markers only. Set the image width explicitly. When using this option, a height must also be set.

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.marker.symbol

Might be only way to get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a relationship between the plot width and the spacing that is used. I see from the code that e.g.:

```
cellWidth = this.chart.plotWidth / cols, cellHeight = this.chart.plotHeight / rows
```

So if the plot is very wide then it will utilize that space. Although not ideal, you could lock down either `chart.width` or `#container { max-width: 320px; ... }` to a size that gives you very little padding between columns.

See e.g. how I've used `320px` for [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/dL0bz8fs/).

Comment: Thank you - this is a very insightful answer. However - it's a pretty fragile solution. I can carefully set the plot width to produce the desired effect. However, if the plot height ever changes (e.g., because the legend gets taller), then it stops working. In other words, the plot width needs to match the plot height (after subtracting out the chart's title and legend heights), which could easily change.